# Selenium 2 Testing Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, testing, object, selenium-webdriver

i'm testing javascript in selenium 2 webdriver under visual studio 2010.
is there any good ways to call method belonged to current javascript-object on page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to get the innertext of elements that are hidden:
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriverInstance).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", this.element).ToString();

The way ExecuteScript is implemented is very similar to String.Format with params object passed in as the second parameter.